# How can I have a collection that contains only persisted Ember Data records, excluding records that live on the client-side and are not persisted?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Assuming I have 3 users in the backend:

```
let users = this.get('store').findAll('user'); 
console.log(users.get('length'));// => 3, e.g. [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}] 
this.get('store').createRecord('user');
console.log(users.get('length')); // => 4, e.g. [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, **{id: null}**]
```

How can I retrieve a list of *only* persisted records, i.e., only records that have an ID assigned to them?

I realize that I can manually filter records that has no ID whenever I need to consume persisted users, but that looks messy and counterintuitive.
Most importantly with a manual approach I can't keep one reference to the collection, like what I had in the `users` variable there, meaning the collection can't be computed, doesn't updates with new records, etc.
I skimmed through Ember's docs but I found nothing of use, have I missed something there?
How can I only get a collection of persisted records from Ember's `store`?

Answer (score 1):

You can filterBy `isNew` property.

```
   let users = this.get('store').findAll('user').then(function(result){
     return result.filterBy('isNew', false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, inspired by kumkanillam's `filterBy` example, the difference lies in that my approach utilizes Ember's computed properties, meaning it *syncs with additions to Ember Data records*, which was my main concern.
The code is extracted as a utility method to be plugged in easily.
`utils/only-persisted.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function (modelName) {
    return Ember.computed(`${modelName}.@each.isNew`, function () {
        return this.get(modelName).filterBy('isNew', false);
    });
};
```

and in a controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import onlyPersisted from 'utils/only-persisted';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    users: onlyPersisted('model')
});
```